# Javascript choosing data from an array to create a set list for chart use

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script below that builds a barchart but I need to pull the data points from my array, the array data is always random and the user gets to choose which data they want as the x axis and what data will be the y axis.

```
var myArray = ["Month,Expenditure,Income,Year", "January,187458,297664,1","February,104967,274354,1","March,202394,343509,1","April,187532,94652,1","May,138745,206456,1","June,234857,143657,1","July,193453,203433,1","August,96343,45064,1","September,371298,505635,1","October,63756,85635,1", "November,45363,14355,1", "December,98642,173125,1"];

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title:{
        text: title.value
    },
    axisY: {
        title: yaxis.value
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [
        { y: , label: },
    ]
}]
});
  chart.render();
}
```

So if the user selects yaxis as being Expenditure and xaxis as being Month, the data points will be built as { y: 18458, label: January},and will repeat over until all data has been used under those headings.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this, I have made drop downs to declare what values they want within x and y axis. The names are called via this;

```
var xaxis = document.getElementsByName('xaxis')[0];
var yaxis = document.getElementsByName('yaxis')[0];
```

Comment: You want convert myArray  to object?

Comment: please provide an example of the desired structure you're trying to make

Is it an array of objects containing Month, Expenditure, Income, and Year fields?

Or an object of arrays where each contains a list of months, a list of expenditures, etc..?

Or something else?

Comment: The desired structure would be when the user selects the xaxis as "month" and the yaxis as "Expenditure" the code will sift through and pull out each data element under that heading. So the desired outcome would be: { y: 18458, label: January }...{ y: 98642, label: December}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so as you're working with CanvasJS charts just write some code that will update your charts according to the user selection.

Here is the docs how to work with data in CanvasJS https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/working-with-data/

I guess every time user selects the axis you need to check whether both axises are selected and if yes - re-render the chart.

```
function updateChart() {
  let newData = [];
  myArray.forEach(function(dataEl) {
    // update newData with each data element
  });
  chart.options.data[0].dataPoints = newData;
}
```

Also you would need to change the chart options like the `axisY` option

In the end it's all about reading CanvasJS docs and updating chart data based on your own demand.

**UPD:**

Just because you asked, here is the code for you (beware of Month being at Y axis, but I've added handling for this - switched chart type to "bar")

```js
var myArray = ["Month,Expenditure,Income,Year", "January,187458,297664,1",
        "February,104967,274354,1", "March,202394,343509,1", "April,187532,94652,1",
        "May,138745,206456,1", "June,234857,143657,1", "July,193453,203433,1",
        "August,96343,45064,1", "September,371298,505635,1",
        "October,63756,85635,1", "November,45363,14355,1",
        "December,98642,173125,1"];

    const select1 = document.querySelector('select[name=xaxis]');
    const select2 = document.querySelector('select[name=yaxis]');

    myArray[0].split(',').forEach(item => {
        select1.appendChild(document.createElement('option')).textContent = item;
        select2.appendChild(document.createElement('option')).textContent = item;
    });


    function generateBar() {

        var title = document.getElementById("chartTitle");
        var xaxis = document.getElementsByName('xaxis')[0];
        var yaxis = document.getElementsByName('yaxis')[0];

        let type = 'column';
        let xaxisVal = xaxis.value;
        let yaxisVal = yaxis.value;
        if (yaxisVal === "Month") {
            type = 'bar'; // for this case bar type
            xaxisVal = yaxis.value;
            yaxisVal = xaxis.value; // Y cannot be non-integer
        }

        let columns = myArray[0].split(',');

        var dataPoints = myArray.slice(1).map((el) => {
            let dataParts = el.split(',');
            return {
                y: parseInt(dataParts[columns.indexOf(yaxisVal)]),
                label: dataParts[columns.indexOf(xaxisVal)]
            }
        });

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            animationEnabled: true,
            theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2",
            title:{
                text: title.value
            },
            axisY: {
                title: yaxis.value
            },
            data: [{
                type: type,
                dataPoints: dataPoints
            }]
        });
        chart.render();

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <p>X-Axis Data</p><p><select name="xaxis">
</select></p><p>Y-Axis Data</p><p><select name="yaxis"></select></p>
    <p>Create a Title for Your Chart</p><input type="text" id="chartTitle"><p>
    <button onclick="generateBar()">Generate Chart</p>
</table>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>

<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: in both cases you need a function, a trigger which will check whether both drop downs are "set" by the user and if yes - run the updateChart (or createChart, doesnt matter) function; add same event listener on both drop downs and check whether both of them are set

Comment: I understand that I need to amend the dataPoints array but I dont know how to split my current array into the drop down selections then push them all into a new array

Comment: please see my edited version - working example, you can run it

Comment: This worked amazingly, though I have one more problem to deal with if you could help me? I've updated my code

Answer (score 1):

Down below is what my current code looks like;

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <p>X-Axis Data</p><p><select name="xaxis">
    </select></p><p>Y-Axis Data</p><p><select name="yaxis"></select></p>
    <p>Create a Title for Your Chart</p><input type="text" id="chartTitle"><p>
    <button onclick="generateBar()">Generate Chart</p>
    </table>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
<script>
var myArray = ["Month,Expenditure,Income,Year", "January,187458,297664,1", 
"February,104967,274354,1", "March,202394,343509,1", "April,187532,94652,1", 
"May,138745,206456,1", "June,234857,143657,1", "July,193453,203433,1", 
"August,96343,45064,1", "September,371298,505635,1", 
"October,63756,85635,1", "November,45363,14355,1", 
"December,98642,173125,1"];

const select1 = document.querySelector('select[name=xaxis]');
const select2 = document.querySelector('select[name=yaxis]');

myArray[0].split(',').forEach(item => {
select1.appendChild(document.createElement('option')).textContent = item;
select2.appendChild(document.createElement('option')).textContent = item;
});


function generateBar() {

var title = document.getElementById("chartTitle");
var xaxis = document.getElementsByName('xaxis')[0];
var yaxis = document.getElementsByName('yaxis')[0];

function updateChart() {
  let newData = [];
  myArray.forEach(function(dataEl) {
    // update newData with each data element
  });
  chart.options.data[0].dataPoints = newData;
}

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
  title:{
    text: title.value
    },
    axisY: {
title: yaxis.value
},
  data: [{
    type: "column",
    dataPoints: []
  }]
});
chart.render();

 }
</script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Now I need to make it so the drop down selects the data I need from the array and organises it to fit the dataPoints array.